# Error when opening Word document that was created by VSTO Template

Tags: deployment, vsto

I have created a new Visual Studio *Word 2010 Template* project, now I want to deploy it using a Windows Installer setup.

I followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) using Visual Studio 2012 with InstallShield 2013LE.

After installing the setup and opening the Word Template, it seems to work fine. However, after saving the template as *.dotx-document and opening it again the *Installing Office customization* dialog appears.

The message says *There was an error during installation: Downloading file file:///[Path to the dotx file]/WordTemplate.vsto did not succeed.*

To check whether I've made an error creating the setup and registry entries, I also tried Advanced Installer 10.9 Office Add-In setup, that creates the required entries automatically. It also fails with the same error message.

There is nothing special about the VSTO Addin. I started a new project for testing purposes, that adds a ribbon and a header to the Word Template file.

Finally I tried the built in Click-Once installer, with success, newly created documents can be opened without any exception. But it comes with some limitations. I would like to add some files and let the user choose the installation path, what doesn't seem possible.

So what am I missing to deploy my VSTO AddIn?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that such a problem is coming from proxy server issues. The proxy server on the client machine is blocking the download of your vsto file that is considered as an executable file.Unfortunately the only solution I see was stipulated in an old post proposing to zip your installer and to send it to users ( which is not optimal, I must agree).

You must also run a command to clear the app cache any time you deploy (from your windows console):

```
rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: There isn't any proxy server defined, as far as you mean that settings found under Control Panel - Internet Options.
But I'll check your caching tip.